# Title app name in Snap Store is strange

Tags: dpkg, debian-installer

I created a *.deb file using dpkg.
When I try to open my file using Snap Store the name of my app is strange, for example instead of display "My New App", appear "mynewapp", it's the name of the package "MyNewApp" in lower case in the file "DEBIAN/control".
I don't understand why Snap Store doesn't use the property "Name" in "/usr/share/applications/MyNewApp.desktop" ?
How to display in Snap Store my app name instead of the package name ?

Thanks